# How to generate an AWS String condition using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following code, but can not get the end section with StringEquals to print the correct value running cloudformation.

```
Parameters:
  OpenIDClientIdList:
    Type: String
    Description: Open ID client ID 
    Default: urn:dev.aws.services.xxxxx.com

  OpenIDURL:
    Type: String
    Description: Open ID URL
    Default: "sts.windows.net/dddddd-rr444-ssss-94c3-7484898492d/"

Resources:
  OpenIDCAssumeReadOnlyRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: OpenIDCAssumeReadOnlyRole
      ManagedPolicyArns: [arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess]
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Federated: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:oidc-provider/${OpenIDURL}
          Action: sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
          Condition:
            StringEquals: !Sub
              - ''
              - - '${OpenIDURL}:aud:'
                - '${OpenIDClientIdList}'
```

Expected Condition String value

```
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts.windows.net/dddddd-rr444-ssss-94c3-7484898492d/:aud": "urn:dev.aws.services.xxxxx.com"
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the current value which is incorrect?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `!Sub` properly. Here's how the condition should look like:

```
Condition:
  StringEquals: 
    Fn::Base64: !Sub
    - |
      "${OPENIDURL}:aud": "${OPENIDCLIENTIDLIST}"
    - OPENIDURL: !Ref OpenIDURL
      OPENIDCLIENTIDLIST: !Ref OpenIDClientIdList
```

Comment: Thanks @Paolo, i tried aboce suggestion but got

`Template error: One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments. Specify a string as first argument, and an optional second argument to specify a mapping of values to replace in the string`

Comment: @manthaRIBBS I've fixed my answer, could you try again ?